# Syscfg error KNL - Error: Failed in export HII base address from SMI driver

Tags: linux, bios, xeon-phi

```
sudo /bin/syscfg/syscfg /d biossettings "Cluster Mode"
sudo /bin/syscfg/syscfg /d biossettings "Memory Mode"
```

I tried these syscfg commands on KNL(Knights Landing) but it gives this error.

```
No data returned from CR

Error: Failed in export HII base address from SMI driver
```

I was able to save BIOS setting using this command:

```
sudo /bin/syscfg/syscfg /s
```

But it gives me the same error when I try to restore it:

```
sudo /bin/syscfg/syscfg /r syscfg.INI /b
Restoring file syscfg.INI in progress...
Error: Failed in export HII base address from SMI driver
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably too late, but in case anyone else sees this later--

It can sometimes help to reset the BMC: 'syscfg /rbmc'.  You can also try resetting the node manager: 'syscfg /rnm'.

If that fails, consider potentially reinstalling the BMC (e.g. using Intel's 'one-boot flash' update utility, or alternately via another bootable media approach or via the EFI shell).  I have seen issues like this from a bad install of the BMC that was interrupted partway through the process by an iKVM connection failure.

Make sure the dependencies for syscfg are all correctly installed in the first place before resorting to more drastic measures, though.